# Counterxample of representation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, duality-theorems, vector-space-isomorphism

Give an example of non-degenerate scalar product $\langle,\rangle$ on a vector space $V$ such that the application
$$\varphi : V\to V^* : v\mapsto L_v$$defined by $L_v(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me what you are asking. Could you be more precise?

Comment: I hope the question clear

Comment: @ZevChonoles and I edited your question almost simultaneously. Feel free to roll back to his version if you prefer it (this applies to everyone).

Comment: In fact, a vector space is isomorphic to its dual if and only if it is finite-dimensional. Thus you just need to find an infinite-dimensional one.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: @HanulJeon, but that fact is considerably more complicated to prove...

Comment: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-vector-space-not-isomorphic-to-its-double-dual/

Answer (score 2):

Consider the vector space $V$ of all infinite sequences $(x_i)_{i\geq0}$ of real numbers with finitely many non-zero terms, and endow it with the inner product such that $$\langle(x_i)_{i\geq0},(y_i)_{i\geq0}\rangle=\sum_{i\geq0}x_iy_i.$$ There is a linear function $\phi:V\to\mathbb R$ such that $$\phi((x_i)_{i\geq0})=\sum_{i\geq0}x_i$$ for all sequences $(x_i)_{i\geq0}\in V$, and you can easily check that it is not in the image of the canonical map $V\to V^*$. Indeed, no vector $(\xi_i)_{i\geq0}$ in $V$ exists such that $$\sum_{i\geq0}x_i\xi_i=\sum_{i\geq0}x_i$$ for all $(x_i)_{i\geq0}\in V$.

Comment: I did not know how check that it is not in the image of the canonical map V→V∗ ?

Comment: Well, the last sentence in the answer gives you an almost complete hint.